# generating you tor hostname from your tor private_key with python

Tags: python, rsa, private-key, hostname, tor

I've been trying to generate my tor hostname from my private_key with python3.
I've used this [tutorial(java)](https://timtaubert.de/blog/2014/11/using-the-webcrypto-api-to-generate-onion-names-for-tor-hidden-services/) and tried to change it to what i want to achieve, but i cant seem to generate my hostname. I suspect that the error lies somewhere in the slicing at the last line, but i cant find any documentation about it.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from base64 import b32encode as b32
import hashlib

privkey= open('privkey',"r")
#print(key.read())
key = RSA.importKey(privkey.read())
pubkey = key.publickey()
print(b32(hashlib.sha1(pubkey.exportKey()[22:).digest()[:10]))
```

also, my goal is to do it as easy understandable as possible, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515593/generating-private-key-and-hostname-for-tor-hidden-service-in-python) seems overly complicated to me.

Answer (score 0):

aye I know this question is old but maybe my answer will benefit other people like me who were trying to do something similar and stumbled upon this question. I think I figured it out - I used some of your code and some of the code from PyShallot and it's working for me.

```
import hashlib
from hashlib import sha1
import rsa
from pyasn1.type import univ, namedtype
from pyasn1.codec.der import encoder
from base64 import b32encode
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

class RSAPublicKey(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
            namedtype.NamedType('modulus', univ.Integer()),
            namedtype.NamedType('publicExponent', univ.Integer())
            )

pubkey, privkey = rsa.newkeys(1024)
privkey = privkey.save_pkcs1(format='PEM')
key = RSA.importKey(privkey)
n = key.n
e = key.e
public_key = RSAPublicKey()
public_key.setComponentByName('modulus', n)
public_key.setComponentByName('publicExponent', e)
pubkey = encoder.encode(public_key)
onion = b32encode(sha1(pubkey).digest())[:16].lower()+'.onion'
print str(onion)
print str(privkey)
```

The code above prints an onion address and the corresponding private key. PyShallot seems to work by calculating a public key and private key piece by piece instead of using an RSA library. I used the rsa module to generate a private key and the Crypto module to extract the individual RSA parameters, and then I used the code from PyShallot to calculate the public key. From there I could derive the onion address. It's really ugly and hacky, and there's definitely a better way to do it that's faster and doesn't use so many libraries. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right, just needed to slice the digest at 16 bytes, then slice the hash at 16 characters:

```
key_hash = b32(hashlib.sha1(pubkey.exportKey()[22:]).digest()[:16])
print(key_hash[:16].lower() + ".onion")
```